# Python - Mandatory 3 decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I'm stuck on a subject.
I have a float number with a value of 0.150. Except that in my program in python, my value displays 0.15.

I want to force the display of 0.150 without converting the number into a character string.
Do you know a function, a library that could help me?

Thanks for your help !

EDIT :
Here my field Odoo declare :

```
    posX = fields.Float(digits=(4, 3), string="Position X", required=True)
```

It works fine for the xml field. I have 0.150.

However, when I use a Python value dictionary, the result displayed is 0.15. This poses a problem in my program. I need 0.150 in float and not in string

Code to use my value :

```
        values += [{
            'name': element.name,
            'posX': element.posX,
            'posY': element.posY,
            'width': element.width,
            'height': element.height,
        }]
```

Here the resut it's 0.15. Why ?

Comment: using f strings: `f"{0.15:.3f}"`

Comment: If you're displaying it (in *any* form), it's being converted to a string.

Comment: Use field [digits](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Float) attribute

Comment: Thanks. But element.posX == 0.15. 
I'm working on abscissas and ordinates in Odoo to place items on PDF documents for an electronic signature project.

0.15 is not accepted. My constraints are 3 decimals.
If write 0.150 raw, then it works

Answer (score 0):

Float 0,15 or 0,150 are exactly the same number for python. You can only show the extra 0 in Odoo nieuws and on pdf reports but not store it in the python variable.

For the views and pdf you can use this code:

```
 <t t-esc="'{0:,.3f}'.format(int(values.posX))" />
```